# StatusBar menu does not show up when using external screen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm using the code below to show the status bar menu on the right click and show the application on the left click.

To achieve that, we need to detach the menu (`statusBarItem.menu = nil`) once it is closed. Otherwise, we would stop receiving `statusBarButtonDidClick` event and left-click would not work.

However, when I attach an external screen after right-click menu is getting closed immediately. The problem is in the line: `statusBarItem.button?.performClick(nil)`, but without that menu would not appear instantly.

My guess is that `performClick` is trying to click on another screen which closes the menu on the active screen.

Is there any way to fix it or achieve the same functionality without `performClick`?

```swift
func createStatusBarItem() {
    statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.squareLength))

    if let button = statusBarItem.button {
        button.image = Asset.Icons.statusbar.image
        button.image?.size = CGSize(width: 16, height: 16)
        button.target = self
        button.action = #selector(statusBarButtonDidClick)
    }
    statusBarItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
}

func menuDidClose(_ menu: NSMenu) {
    statusBarItem.menu = nil
}

@objc private func statusBarButtonDidClick(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
    let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

    if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
        let statusBarMenu = StatusBarMenu()
        statusBarMenu.delegate = self

        statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
        statusBarItem.button?.performClick(nil)
    } else {
        application.showApplication()
    }
}
```